# How do I model atoms with Moebius strips?

Tags: elements, periodic-table

This question came to me while I was trying to model the list of elements (Mendeleïev), especially their masses and number of electrons.
It came to my mind that it might be easier to model each element as [Moebius Strip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_strip) with $n$ twists.

If this is possible, is there any literature about this subject? A methodology to do this?

**----EDIT----**

Ok, 
it took me a while to go deep into the subject in order to present "concrete thoughts" but I finally could summarize them into the following spreadsheet:

https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=b20ec7aa903ebb07!701&authkey=!AE5lfNOaYgtJWNg&ithint=file%2cxlsx

The model has a R² = 0.9976 (what I think is pretty good as a first try)

Please check the [spreadsheet](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=b20ec7aa903ebb07!701&authkey=!AE5lfNOaYgtJWNg&ithint=file%2Cxlsx) in the following order:

A) **Observation VS calculation**

B) **Racionale** ( that presents the reasoning used to make the calculations used by the model)

C) **Consequences** (the rational consequences of the model --> I'm NOT sure that the reasoning expressed in this table is valid

D) **Data** ( the data and its source used to make the ratio between 'calculations' and 'observations')

Comment: Of interest to you in your quest: [The Internet Periodic Table Database](http://www.meta-synthesis.com/webbook/35_pt/pt_database.php).

Comment: Topology has also been a weak mathematical area for me, but I don't think that sort of representation would help. The periodic table and the Aufbau diagram are the two keys used to introduce inorganic chemistry. I just don't comprehend how a Mobius strip would simplify either or combine either in some novel way. Science is always looking for new ideas,  so if you have more concrete thoughts on this we'd be happy to critique them. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aufbau_principle

Comment: Hi @MaxW it took me a while to go deep into the subject in order to present you "concrete thoughts" but I finally could summarize them into the following spreadsheet:
https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=b20ec7aa903ebb07!701&authkey=!AE5lfNOaYgtJWNg&ithint=file%2cxlsx
The model has a R² = 0.9976 (what I think is pretty good as a first try) and, **if** the racionale (reasoning) is correct, the consequences seems pretty good to me.

Comment: (continuing)
please check the spreadsheet in the following order:

A) Observation VS calculation

B) Racionale ( that are the reasoning used to make the calculations used by the model)

C) Consequences (the rational consequences of the model --> I'm NOT sure that the reasoning expressed in this table is valid

D) Data ( the data and its source used to make the ratio between 'calculations' and 'observations')

Comment: I don't have any idea of what you're trying to calculate in the spreadsheet.

Comment: I'm trying to calculate the atomic weight of each element in relation to the number of electrons (or protons --> atomic number)

Comment: Atomic weight and atomic number could easily be shown in a list ordered by atomic number. The importance of the periodic table is the relationships between the chemical reactivity of the elements.

Comment: hmm, well I understand that this spreadsheet may not have any practical use then, but would this make the model incorrect? Actually I'm just _trying_ to make an simpler model to find the atomic  weight of an element.